# uninstall / deactivate ssh client only on linux server

Tags: linux, ssh, brute-force-attacks

How can I uninstall or completely deactivate ssh client only. I still need server to log in.
I just wonna pretend ssh brute force attacks commming out from my server.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can uninstall openssh-client.  Eg. on Debian

```
dpkg -r openssh-client
```

Answer (score 0):

A host that allows an unauthorized person to run arbitrary commands is compromised, you have lost. Removing the system OpenSSH can be done, but only prevents one thing they might attempt to do. They can just as well download their own payload, which might not be ssh based at all.

Think about more complete controls to limit what users can do. Application whitelist, *outbound* firewall, stricter access controls (SELinux), only grant shell access as needed. Plus logging when denials happen, to understand what is being attempted.